# How To create a table nam from variable ?? Phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

i want to build a table from a variable as

```
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  "'+DateNTime+'" (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, phoneno TEXT, status TEXT, profile TEXT, hot_button TEXT, meeting TEXT, note TEXT)');
```

**DateNTime** is The Varible in which table name is include. 
In **DateNTime** i am handling Time n date or pick time n date
please help

Comment: `DateNTime` seems like a ***very*** oddly-named variable for something that contains a table name...

Comment: That code looks OK. What is the problem?